# Is this insect some kind of pest?

Tags: species-identification, entomology

I live near Paris, France. I would like to know if this small flying insect was some kind of pest or not. More specifically, I want to know if it might be a meal moth or a clothing moth. Here is the little fella :[image][image]

It's approx 1.5 cm (0.6 in) long

Answer (score 2):

This is [Hypena obsitalis](http://www.pyrgus.de/Hypena_obsitalis_en.html), aka the Bloxworth snout, a moth of the family Noctuidae.

Personally I hate the word pest, but this little beauty eats *Parietaria* und *Urtica* (Nettle) so I can't think of anyone seeing this as a pest species.